# Circular queue size using mod

Tags: java, arrays, queue, circular-queue

Let's say I implement a circular queue using an array. How could I calculate the size of the queue? By size I mean the number of elements between the front and the rear. I want to use the modulo operation.

I have the capacity of the array, and the positions of the front and the rear of the queue. I don't known what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I calculate the size of the queue?

I would use

```
size = (start - end + mod) % mod;
```

This assumes the buffer is never completely at capacity. An alernative is to use a start and end which is without modding

```
size = lastWriteIndex - nextReadIndex;
```

You can mod these value when you look up the index.

Comment: `size = (end - start + mod) % mod;`?

Comment: @saka1029 for a circular buffer the start index could be before the end index.

Comment: Do you mean `start` is `lastWriteIndex`?

Comment: @saka1029 it would be the nextWriteIndex.